# Why are SDEs given in the form $dX_t=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

All the resources I have found state that a Stochastic Differential Equation has the form:
$$dX_t=\mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t$$
Where $B_t$ is Brownian motion. My question has two parts. The first one is: why is an SDE given in this form when regular ODEs are given the apparently more general form
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=f(t,X)?$$
By taking $X$ to be a vector and renaming derivatives to coordinates this expression captures everything from higher order to systems of DEs. Analogously, I would have expected a general SDE to instead look like
$$dX_t=f(t,X_t,B_t)dt\tag{1}$$
But the canonical formulation seems to be just linear in the stochastic term. My guess here is that we can "augment" the state space by letting $Y_t=\begin{bmatrix} X_t \\B_t\end{bmatrix}$ and rewriting $(1)$ as
$$dY_t=\begin{bmatrix}f(t,Y_t)\\ 0\end{bmatrix}dt+\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}dB_t.$$
Is this manipulation correct?

My second question is why can we only use Brownian motion (or perhaps more generally semimartingales) as integrators? Usually SDEs are introduced by discretizing a differential equation and summing the changes in the random process to arrive at a stochastic integral in the limit. Why can we not just replace $B_t$ by any stochastic process?

Comment: Your equation (1) isn't more general since the only integrals appearing are integrals with respect to $dt$. Indeed for reasonable $f$, your equation (1) can be solved pathwise and is just a random ODE. The generic form for an SDE is a generalisation since by taking $\mu = f, \sigma = 0$ one recovers the ODE case and so the generic SDE is the ODE plus some term driven by Brownian Motion. One can generalise from only allowing semimartingales as integrators (cf rough path theory) but this requires more machinery than the Ito & Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals so goes beyond the classical treatment.

Comment: @RhysSteele thank you. I am actually interested in finding a Fokker-Planck type equation for such a generalized ODE (the random process arises as a randomly truncated random Fourier series, so I have no idea if it even is a semimartingale). I am wondering if this rough path theory formulation is useful for deriving such PDEs.